# How to copy a char* array to a std::vector<uint16_t>?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have an array of chars, stored in a `char*`. From this pointer I want to copy the elements from a specific offset to another to a `std::vector<uint16_t>`. I need to combine always two chars, cause they are meant to be one 16 bit value.
The start and end offset is known and I know this values should be integers. But what is the best way to cast and copy this array. It's about 25000 uint values, so it should be an efficient way.

Following a code snippet to make it more clear. The problem with this snippet, it uses each char value as an own integer, but should combine always two chars two one 16 bit value. So the resulting vector has a size of 50688, but it should be 25344.

Simple:

```
char * buf = new char[bufSize];
std::vector<uint16_t> vec;

vec.reserve(numPix);
vec.insert(vec.begin(), &buf[startOffset], &buf[endOffset]);
```

Original:

```
const size_t numPixel = m_cameraParams.width * m_cameraParams.height; // 25344
const size_t numBytesDistance = numPixel * m_distanceByteDepth;       // 50688
const size_t numBytesIntensity = numPixel * m_intensityByteDepth;     // 50688
const size_t numBytesConfidence = numPixel * m_confidenceByteDepth;   // 50688

std::vector<uint16_t> m_distanceMap;
std::vector<uint16_t> m_intensityMap;
std::vector<uint16_t> m_confidenceMap;

char * inputBuffer = new char[bufferSize];
// buffer filled with data received from tcp connection

//-----------------------------------------------
// Extract the Images depending on the informations extracted from the XML part
size_t offsetDistance = offset;
size_t offsetIntensity = offsetDistance + numBytesDistance;
size_t offsetConfidence = offsetIntensity + numBytesIntensity;
offset = offsetConfidence + numBytesConfidence;

m_distanceMap.reserve(numPixel);
m_distanceMap.insert(m_distanceMap.begin(), &inputBuffer[offsetDistance], &inputBuffer[offsetIntensity]);
m_intensityMap.reserve(numPixel);
m_intensityMap.insert(m_intensityMap.begin(), &inputBuffer[offsetIntensity], &inputBuffer[offsetConfidence]);
m_confidenceMap.reserve(numPixel);
m_confidenceMap.insert(m_confidenceMap.begin(), &inputBuffer[offsetConfidence], &inputBuffer[offset]);
```

Comment: What have you tried? and did it not perform well?

Comment: I first copied it element by element using a cast to change the data type and this is really really slow. With `std::copy` a type mismatch came up. Now I use `m_distanceMap.insert(m_distanceMap.begin(), &inputBuffer[offsetDistance], &inputBuffer[offsetIntensity]);` what looks pretty good for the moment, but didn't check the content of the vector at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to copy 1 char to one short, or combine 2 chars into 1 short? Your last sentence is confusing, and the snippet is as well.  I guess another way of asking would be, is this a 16-bit image and you just happen to have a char* buffer? If it's really 16-bit data just resize the vector to the right size and use memcpy.

Comment: I want to combine two chars as one short, but do not know how, without making a cast on each value and copying it.

Comment: Assuming you don't need to swap bytes, I'd use memcpy. It sounds like you don't need to convert anything, you just have a `char*` instead of a `uint16_t*`, but memcpy just moves bytes so it doesn't care about that.

Comment: Can't you just pre allow the memory you need, use memcpy and then declare a uint16_t pointer at the beginning of your new array. Convert to vector<uint16_t> if you want too ?